# How to plot multiple functions in same figure (subplot) in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink, subplot

Similar to what we can do with the subplot command in MATLAB to have many plots in a single figure, How can I plot different graphs in same figure using Simulink?

**Note:**

- I am not asking about multiplotting which I already know how to do that using vector concatenate + scope but it gives me overriding plots. I am unable to find a way that I could have a separate subplot for each function.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Have multiple inputs for your scope (image shows right-click menu)

[image: 1]

2. Show multiple plots from the `layout` menu (up to 16x16 plots) of the open scope

[image: 2]

3. Voilà, subplots! As per [**the documentation**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/scope.html), the first `n` traces will be shown in the first `n` subplots of the layout. Any traces which can't be shown individually will all be grouped within the last subplot.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change the default behaviour of plotting all extra traces in the last subplot? Say I have 4 signals and 3 subplots and I want signal 1 in subplot 1, signal 2 & 3 in subplot 2 and signal 4 in subplot 3.

Comment: @debsim you can use a `mux` block in that case to combine signals 2&3 into one, and use that as the 2nd input to the scope. Then you would have a 3x1 layout on the scope and the 2nd plot should show the two signals.